# How to display all duplicate value

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, inner-join, having-clause

Is there anyway I could display all the duplicate values in mysql using group by and having

```
+---------+--------------+------------+--------+----------+----------+---------+
| ENumber | EmpName      | Birthdate  | Gender | Address  | Salary   | DNumber |
+---------+--------------+------------+--------+----------+----------+---------+
| E001    | GSInocencio  | 1988-01-15 | F      | Munoz    | 18000.00 | D005    |
| E002    | EAVillanueva | 1988-04-20 | F      | Munoz    | 23000.00 | D003    |
| E003    | ALedesma     | 1988-05-25 | M      | CLSU     | 21000.00 | D002    |
| E004    | APGamilla    | 1991-10-15 | F      | Maligaya | 25000.00 | D001    |
| E005    | ACTolentino  | 1989-02-20 | F      | Maligaya | 30000.00 | D002    |
| E006    | ANVillasoto  | 1999-01-05 | M      | CLSU     | 15000.00 | D004    |
| E007    | JPPalada     | 1997-01-10 | M      | Munoz    | 21000.00 | D001    |
| E008    | NTNicodemus  | 1995-04-15 | F      | Maligaya | 22000.00 | D003    |
+---------+--------------+------------+--------+----------+----------+---------+
```

I want to display all the duplicate value in DNumber

```
  +---------+--------------+------------+--------+----------+----------+---------+
| ENumber | EmpName      | Birthdate  | Gender | Address  | Salary   | DNumber |
+---------+--------------+------------+--------+----------+----------+---------+
| E004    | APGamilla    | 1991-10-15 | F      | Maligaya | 25000.00 | D001    |
| E007    | JPPalada     | 1997-01-10 | M      | Munoz    | 21000.00 | D001    |
| E003    | ALedesma     | 1988-05-25 | M      | CLSU     | 21000.00 | D002    |
| E005    | ACTolentino  | 1989-02-20 | F      | Maligaya | 30000.00 | D002    |
| E002    | EAVillanueva | 1988-04-20 | F      | Munoz    | 23000.00 | D003    |
| E008    | NTNicodemus  | 1995-04-15 | F      | Maligaya | 22000.00 | D003    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> display all the duplicate values in mysql using group by and having

There is more than one way to do it, but if you want to use `group by` and `having`, then you can join the table with an aggregate subquery that identifies the duplicates, as follows:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
inner join (
    select dnumber
    from mytable
    group by dnumber
    having count(*) > 1
) x on x.dnumber = t.dnumber
order by t.dnumber, t.enumber
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my Question